# Remove radar chart labels in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to get rid of the label "undefined" from showing at all at the top of my chart, as I only have one dataset and don't need a legend.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJy51.png]

Here's my code:

```
// Radar chart data
var radarData = {
labels : ["Abs","Arms","Back","Butt","Chest","Legs","Shoulders"],
datasets : [
    {
  lavel: "test",
        fillColor: "rgba(102,45,145,.1)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(102,45,145,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
    }
]
};

// Create Radar chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("radarChart").getContext("2d");

var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: "radar",
data: radarData
});
```

Adding "options: [scaleShowLabels=false]" doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "radar",
            data: radarData,
        });
        myNewChart.options.title.text = "top of chart";   // test, total fail
        myNewChart.options.legend.display = false;        // This one does it!
```

So apparently on the radar chart, that top element is called the legend.  I was able to place a watch on myNewChart object in Chrome and step thru the code in dev tools.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that in [Chart.js version 3](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.1.1/configuration/title.html), the `options` now have a `plugins` inner field, in which such options are to be configured.
So now it is:

```js
options:{
      plugins:{
         legend:{
            display:false
         }
      }
   }
```

Or programmatically:

```
myNewChart.options.plugins.legend.display = false;
```